# Array boundaries on java and .length

Tags: java, android

keys array have been defined as follows:

```
    keys = new char[] {resolv, 'А', 'Б', 'В', 'Г', 'Д', 'Е', 
                                'Ё', 'Ж', 'З', 'И', 'Й', 'К', 
                                'Л', 'М', 'Н', 'О', 'П', 'Р', 
                                'С', 'Т', 'У', 'Ф', 'Х', 'Ц', 
                                'Ч', 'Ш', 'Щ', 'Ъ', 'Ы', 'Ь',
                                'Э', 'Ю', 'Я'};
```

'resolv' is a constant char value of 0x00, but that's not relevant for this issue.

Now, this code raises "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=34; index=34" exception *sometimes*:

```
protected void LoadKeyRects() {
    keyRects = new Rect[keys.length];
    // Solve key
    keyRects[0] = resRect;


    // Rest of keys
    int x, y;
    for (int i=1; i<keys.length; i++) {
        y = 214 + ( 87 * ((i-1)/11));
        x = 7 + (((i-1)%11)*71);
        keyRects[i] = new Rect (x, y, x+71, y+87);
    }
}
```

So far I haven't been able to reproduce the error by myself, but I have got enough reports from BugSense in third party devices to be concerned about it. It seems like sometimes keyRects[i] may refer to keyRects[keys.length] despite the i

Any ideas?

Comment: Is `keys` final? Can you be **sure** that no one ever re-assigns `keys` (especially while `LoadKeyRects` is running)?

Comment: error at which line? ur loop doesn't seem to cross keys.length

Comment: If `keys` is not changing, this is one of the signs of the end of the world.

Comment: @JoachimSauer The key is not final, but that does not seem to be the problem: if you look at the exception, it says array length is 34 when it crashes. The problem is why the index is 34 too...

Comment: @MarounMaroun BugSense didn't provide me the line number, only the method. I think it is something related with proguard, despite I uploaded the mappings.txt file and the method names are resolved with it. Anyway giving the code there is only a line in which a value is assigned to an array element, so...

Comment: @Fran: assume that `keys` points to a 34-element array when the method starts (and you create an equally-big `keyRects` array). Then sometimes during the first 34 iterations *another thread* replaces `keys` with a reference to a 35-element array (or bigger, doesn't matter). Then your loop will run until `i=34` and `keyRects[i]` will throw exactly that exception. Note that you never index into `keys` here, so the problematic array must be `keyRects`.

Comment: Actually I believe @JoachimSauer has a very valid point. If keys can be modified, and was modified, an index of 34 is very much possible. I am thinking russian characters are not the only valid keys you use in your app?

Comment: @JoachimSauer Sorry but that makes non sense to me (that does not mean that it doesn't have sense, anyway): if the array is changed by a, let's say, 35 elements array, it won't crash at keyRects[34]. On the other hand the exception wouldn't say "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=34;", but whatever different length value the array has when it crashes.

Comment: @Fran, Joachim means that you could get into a situation where `keyRects` has 34 elements but `keys` has 35; which means that `i` could get to 34 within the loop.

Comment: @Fran: `keyRects` can't be changed! But `keys` can! You're checking for `keys.length` but indexing into `keyRects`! As a workaround, you could try copying `keys` (or just `keys.length`) into a local variable to avoid modifications while the method is running (but that would likely just postpone the problem, if `keys` changes under you, then there **is** definitely a problem).

Comment: In how many different ways do you set the value of ``keys``?

Comment: it would be a best practice to save keys.length a local copy before the for loop

Comment: @IanGil Read my answer about my why I don't think Joachim's hypothesis is valid. For me if the exception saying the array length is 34 when crashed is enough for discarding that. Apart from that, the array is not changed in any other thread, and despite I support several keyboards, I use one different class per language, and additionally there is no other one keyboard supported with more letters than Russian.

Comment: @Fran, just going in another direction for a minute - you said you have the method name but not the line number.  Is it possible that it's not actually this method, but one that overrides it in a subclass?

Comment: @Fran: **the exception message tells you the size of `keysRects`**. I'm telling you that `keys` changes size! You're *indexing* into one array and *checking the length of another*!

Comment: @JoachimSauer You have a point there, indeed. Although I do not touch those arrays in any other thread as far as I know, I would change keys.length by keyRects.length in the for loop condition, release a new version and see what happens... I will come back here to tell you, so if you want to write your comment as an answer and it worked, I would select it as the prefered one.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Fran: you always say: the array length is 34 when crashed! its always the array length. it cant changes after the declaration with [keys.length]. the exception only tells you the length of the array. like joachim said.

Comment: @Fran: personally I'd make sure that `keys` is final, because if you don't *expect* it to change, then tell that to the compiler ;-)

Comment: @JoachimSauer Keys cannot be final. There is a class Keyboard that has descendants like KeyboardEnglish, KeyboardFrench, KeyboardSpanish and KeyboardRussian, each one initializes the keys array with different values, depending on an user setting.

Comment: @Fran changing your loop to use ``keyRects.length`` may get you around this immediate problem, but it won't address the problem that ``keys`` is likely getting modifed by multiple threads which could lead to further unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @Fran: then you really need a factory that can construct those instances (depending on the user settings) and make sure that the keyboard classes themselves stay final.

Comment: @ChrisKnight Well, we do not know if that's the case yet. My app just run two threads at same time, and I am pretty sure that only one changes such variable -the "other" thread is the UI thread, that only takes care of updating the UI graphical interface- and it does it just one time at class initialization.

So the thread thing is just an hypothesis, that it is not very strong BTW, but it happens that so far I haven't found another better to explain the problem, so it is worth to try it.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Will make any difference if I declare such method as:

 protected synchronized void LoadKeyRects()

???

Comment: @Fran: probably not if whatever modifies `keys` (if that's the fact) is not also synchronized. And if, as you say, `keys` is not *supposed to* be modified, then I'd argue that that's the wrong approach anyway.

Comment: @JoachimSauer keys is defined as protected char keys[]; in parent Keyboard class, and it is only modified/init in method PrepareKeys that is called just once from class constructor. No other method writes or changes anything on keys[] array.

Comment: @Fran Could you please search for all occurences of `keys = ` in your project ? Also, please provide full declaration of `keys` from your code. Changing it to `final` as Joachim Sauer pointed out, will solve your issue. ALternatively use `i<keyRects.length` in the loop

Answer (score 4):

I can see the problem in the `for` loop. You use out-of-scope field to end your iteration, which is simply wrong, if you're not accessing the field itself. Also if you did, you should do it differently. Two examples:

```
protected void LoadKeyRects() {
    keyRects = new Rect[keys.length];
    // Solve key
    keyRects[0] = resRect;


    // Rest of keys
    int x, y;
    for (int i=1; i<keyRects.length; i++) {
        y = 214 + ( 87 * ((i-1)/11));
        x = 7 + (((i-1)%11)*71);
        keyRects[i] = new Rect (x, y, x+71, y+87);
    }
}
```

This will work properly without any `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` for sure. If you need to access or even modify the `keys` array, do it that way:

```
protected void LoadKeyRects() {
    final char[] localKeys = keys;

    keyRects = new Rect[localKeys.length];
    // Solve key
    keyRects[0] = resRect;


    // Rest of keys
    int x, y;
    for (int i=1; i<localKeys.length; i++) {
        y = 214 + ( 87 * ((i-1)/11));
        x = 7 + (((i-1)%11)*71);
        keyRects[i] = new Rect (x, y, x+71, y+87);
    }

    // if you need to change the keys, uncomment the next line
    // keys = localKeys;
}
```